# Difference between SSM and SSR

Tags: anova

[image]Are SSM(sum square of mean?) and SSR(sum of square due to regression) are same or they are two different things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same if your linear regression model only has an intercept term. Otherwise they are different.

SSR is defined as $\sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$, where $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_{1,i} + \cdots + \hat{\beta}_p x_{p,i}$.

If you only have an intercept, your model is $y_i = \beta_0 + \epsilon_i$, your estimate is $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}$, and SSR simplifies to

$$
\sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{\beta}_0)^2 = \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2 = \text{SSM}.
$$

In general, this is always true:

$$
\sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2 = \sum_i (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 + \sum_i (\hat{y}_i - \bar{y})^2
$$
which is a famous decomposition of variance: SSM = SSR + SSE.

Comment: Thanks, @Taylor , i am working with simple regression model.

Comment: No problem @KhanSaab. Just a heads up be careful of the word "simple." "Simple linear regression" generally refers to the model with one predictor, or $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$. If that's the case, $\text{SSR} \neq \text{SSM}$.

Comment: Sorry for to many questions, i just edited my question and regression line is indeed given by y = a + bx + error. SSM and SSE are both given by difference between actual point and expected point? Can you check above where i make a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is typical to label $\sum(y_i - \hat y_i)^2 = SSE$ while $\sum(\hat y_i - \bar y)^2$ is labeled either $SSR$ or $SSM$. Most sources use $\sum(y_i - \bar y)^2 = SST$, so that the decomposition of variance is generally either $SST = SSE + SSM$ or $SST = SSE + SSR$. See, for example, http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/anovareg.htm or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aq8VU5KLmkY
So, the answer to your question is that $SSR$ and $SSM$ are just two common notations for the same quantity.